# Is there any way to make an image to be exact aspect ratio in a button in android?

Tags: android, xml

I can't use scale-type because it's not an imageview.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6MXbqm4_MKPVWdQbzhEZ01oaU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried ImageButton ?  Can you share some XML markup or code of how you wound up with a skewed image?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6MXbqm4_MKPa0NqZktsZXZxTXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the thing is if i use imageview also sometimes the image is skewed.do we have a universal size so it can be fit like original image (eg :480x272).

Comment: Why aren't you using ImageButton?

Comment: i have more than 5 pages like this and i coded as button and also even if i use imagebutton which will be the best scaletype..
and sir is there any ratio to crop so i can get it as orginal